# Order of a permutation, how to calculate

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

I know this is a basic question however I am slightly confused what to do if the permutation contains the same element twice in cycle notation.

For example: the permutation $(1  2  3)(2  4  1)$, how would I calculate the order when $2$ maps to $3$ and $4$? Is it just the same? Does $p=3$

Comment: Permutations are applied from right to left.  We have $1\mapsto 3$ since the permutation on the right first sends it to $2$ and then on the left continues moving it to $3$, we have $2\mapsto 4$ since the permutation on the right sends it to $4$ and the one on the left doesn't touch it any more beyond that, it sends $3\mapsto 1$ since the permutation on the right doesn't touch it and the one on the left moves it from $3$ to $1$, etc... giving the permutation $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\3&4&1&2\end{pmatrix}$.  Seeing it in tworow first might help see cyclic: $(1~3)(2~4)$.  Should see order now.

Comment: For future reference, it can be shown that *any* permutation is the union of disjoint cycles. This is good to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you'll need to express $(123)(241)$ in terms of the product of *disjoint cycles.*
$(123)$ and $(241)$ are **not** disjoint cycles, as you note, since both share the elements $1, 2$.

To do so, you start from the right cycle, and compose with the left cycle.  So, in the right-hand cycle, we have $1\mapsto 2$ and in the lefthand cycle, $2\mapsto 3$.  Now since $3\mapsto 3$ (righthand)  and $3\mapsto 1$ (lefthand, we have the cycle (13).

In the end, you'll find $$\phi = (123)(241)=(13)(24)$$

Second, the order of a one-cycle permutation is its length; to find the order of a product of more than one permutation cycle, as is the case here, the order of $\phi$ is the $\operatorname {lcm}$ of the lengths of the cycles.

So we have the product of two $2$-cycles, and hence the order of $\phi$ is equal to the $\operatorname {lcm}(2, 2) = 2$.